# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

A friend of mine copy pasted a libgdx project folder on his pc and sent the project to me(through google drive). We are both using Android Studio. I downloaded and imported the project and it is working properly on the emulator. However it is not working on the desktop. On his pc, it works both in desktop and in the emulator.

When I try to run it in the desktop, Android Studio gives me this error message:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'bouncerGDX - Copy'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
 Searched in the following locations:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.jar

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.jar
 Required by:
     :bouncerGDX - Copy:unspecified
```

How can I fix this? I have no experience with Gradle.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**UPD:**

It seems can't resolve *com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2* dependency for the classpath.

For me, adding the jcenter to *build.gradle* resolves the issue:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
}
```

or, alternatively, the line in *build.gradle*

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

can be changed to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

^^^ this version exist in *repo1.maven.org*

**WRONG SUGGESTION:**

Resolve all dependencies by running gradle task (can be done from Android Studio's terminal):

For Linux:

```
./gradlew buildDependents
```

For Windows:

```
gradlew.bat buildDependents
```

Also, this commands might also help later

Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanIdea idea
```

Windows:

```
gradlew.bat cleanIdea idea
```

This is the reference to libgdx [How-to-setup-development-env](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29) instruction

Comment: I get this error when I try the first command: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: if you're on Windows, it will be: gradlew.bat buildDependents
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Comment: ah yes. I am on windows. I thought the bottom one was the linux example. It started downloading.

Comment: "Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature."  Then it gave me the exact same error.

Comment: but there is something weird: Unzipping C:\Users\WV\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7\gradle-2.14.1-a
ll.zip to C:\Users\WV\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).

It seems I did that for the 2.14.1 not for 2.2.2. I wonder if that would be the reason.

Comment: I think this is the repo downloading issue, the path  "repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2"  - doesn't exist and gradle fails to pull the files from it, I've updated my unsver

Comment: This seemed to fix it. Now I have a different problem which is cause by my own code. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same issue after updating Android Studio 2.2.2 to 2.3.1

```
   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
```

Solution:

Open the gradle location and make changes in build.gradle accordingly(module and project both)

I replaced

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

And gradle build successfully :-)

[gradle location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yoE4.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}
}
```

add google() below jcenter(),this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you hav dependency on the library project **bouncerGDX**
You can open build.gradle of that project and change gradle version which is available with you. e.g.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix for the same error was to configure Android Studio for the proxy I'm stuck behind.

Android Studio + Gradle did not assume system proxy settings, at least not on my copy of macOS. Set your proxy settings in Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy, save them and restart Android Studio. It then prompted me to set Gradle's proxy settings to match Android Studio's. Once I did this, no more error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the maven url solved the issue for me.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solution For Android 2.3.1 built in 2017 April]

In gradle.build(Project)
Add missing repositories 
    mavenLocal() and jcenter()
To 
    buildscript { repositories { }}

Notice there are TWO gradle.build files!! Pick the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was updating **Gradle** as **Android Studio** recommended
[image]

**Solution:**
When you import the project make sure not to update Gradle (click "**Don't remind me again for this project**") and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add this in your build.gradle file]

Note: Use latest gradle version.